# parsing xml using jquery (malformed xml)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<export>
  <Article URL="test">
      <DisplayName>test</DisplayName>
      <Summary>test</Summary>
      <ThumbNail ID="test" URL="test" />
  </Article>
</export>
```

Which I'm looking to parse using jQuery. This works using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://[fqdn]/[filename].xml'
})
.done(function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('Article').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('URL'));
        console.log($(this).find('DisplayName').text());
        console.log($(this).find('Summary').text());
        console.log($(this).find('ThumbNail').attr('URL'));
    });
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
})
```

All output is logged to the console, but at the end I'm getting an error saying the XML is malformed at line 1 column 78 which is causing my entire script to halt.

Is this the right way to go about this?

Adding dataType: "xml", and/or type: "GET", does not help.

Comment: why don't you just try `jQuery.parseXML()` ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil since I can't seem to get that to work. I have tried several examples. Do you have one for me based on my XML file?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the value of the variable `xml` that you get from the ajax success? It seems like `$.parseXML` is working based on the XML content you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

getting your XML in Jquery:

```
var x = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><export> <Article URL='test'>   <DisplayName>test</DisplayName> <Summary>test</Summary><ThumbNail ID='test' URL='test' /></Article></export>";

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(x);
```

and log everything you need:

```
 $(xmlDoc).find('Article').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('URL'));
        console.log($(this).find('DisplayName').text());
        console.log($(this).find('Summary').text());
        console.log($(this).find('ThumbNail').attr('URL'));
    });
```

let me know if it works.